# How to make Frame Independent Timer Clock

Tags: unity, timer

I want to make a frame Independent Timer that it work consistently across different computer configuration.

Comment: Is it game time you want to measure, or realtime? Game time can slow down or speed up if you're modifying `Time.timeScale` for slow-motion effects and the like.

Comment: i just want to make a clock where each time is important and specific event will fire on time. additonally i want to slow and speed up the time ? is this possible

Comment: Jon's answer below gets you what you need

Answer (score 2):

```
// ORIGINAL TIMER COUNTDOWN IN SECONDS
const float TIMER = 3;

// TIMER CURRENT TIME
float Timer;

// RUNS ON EACH FRAME
void Update()
{
    // SUBTRACT DELTA TIME FROM CURRENT TIME
    Timer -= Time.deltaTime;

    // TIMER WENT OFF
    if (Timer <= 0)
    {
        //DO SOMETHING
        Foo();

        // RESET TIMER
        Timer = TIMER;
    }
}
```

Comment: so this will work frame Indepently and how can i speed up

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan you would change the TIMER value to whatever you want.  I added some comments since you seem to be pretty new to this.